# Zip Function without using built in

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function (without using a built in function) that turns this
([f,u,n],[1,2,3,4])
into this [(f,1),(u,2),(n,3)]

Basically taking the first element of both lists and turning them into a tuple, then the second element of both lists, etc.

I have this so far:

```
>> def zipup(lista,listb):
    >> for x in range(len(lista)):
        >>for y in range(len(listb)):
             >>return [(lista[x],listb[y])]
```

But I keep getting this: [(f,1)]

Help?!

Comment: Do you have to make your own `zip` or can you use the builtin?

Comment: are you sure it didn't say global name x ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the variable `i` is not defined, it is not even in the code snippet that you showed ... that a look at the line that the error shows.

As for the zip, take a look at the docs for the standard library for the [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools#itertools.izip), there is a equivalent python implementation that you can use as a guide.

Comment: Python 2 code from `izip` docs won't work on Python 3 (look at the tags). Link to [`zip` builtin](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) instead